# Strange results with execute() on SwingWorker task

Tags: java, swingworker

Java newbie here...caution!

I've set this practice app up using this [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html#bars) as a base. Unfortunately I'm having a problem. If I just run the program, the SwingWorker task works for very small datasets but will just stall part way through larger ones. I know this app isn't the most efficient, but I can't work out why it just stalls (or even where).

I've put the code up [here](https://gist.github.com/937992).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  Pause the worker thread and see where it is 'stuck'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stack trace or use a debugger if you believe the thread has stalled. Should give you an idea. Looking at your code: Make sure you change swing components only in the swing event thread, i.e. your done code should set the text field to the result of your computation.

Comment: Thanks, moving the text update to the done function has at least made it display its progress so far. But it does show that the task is reporting end prematurely. I'm not sure how to get a stack trace from this, nothing apparently "goes wrong" according to java. I'll step through it again with the debugger tho.

Comment: try to wrap the code you have in doInBackground in a `try { } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: Thanks Jochen. It was throwing when I tried to set the progress bar value > 100. I assumed that setting the maximum on the progress bar would allow me to do that, but I was wrong.